# Please provide a valid cache path error in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I'm working with Jetstream library with Laravel 9, And I've deleted the storage folder by the wrong, and then it shows the following error.

> Please provide a valid cache path.

What should I do? I tried the command `composer install`, and I faced the same error! So how can I return back to the storage folder?

Comment: Find one of your previous laravel project, copy and paste the storage folder, then try run it.

Answer (score 1):

create the following

```
storage/app
storage/app/public
storage/framework
storage/framework/cache
storage/framework/cache/data
storage/framework/views
storage/framework/session
storage/logs
```

And use git to manage your code so that accidents like this are easily recovered

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I think these folders should not be empty, right?
If yes, What lines should be placed in these files manually?

Comment: only .gitignore files that make sure that your repository contains empty folders. But as you are not using git then its irrelevant.  If you want them then install a new Laravel project and copy the folder across

Comment: Yes It work, Thanks again <3

Comment: mark it answered?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your terminal.
2. Run `cd YOUR_LARAVEL_PATH` to navigate to the Laravel directory.
3. Run `mkdir storage/framework/{cache,sessions,views}` to create missing directories.
4. Run `php artisan cache:clear`
5. Run `php artisan config:clear`
6. Run `php artisan view:clear`
7. Run `chmod -R 777 storage` to set write permissions (depends on your system).